# Showing TIME(n) is not closed under poly-time reduction

Tags: complexity-theory

I am trying to wrap my head around the following proof

- Choose some language *A* $\in$ $TIME(n^3)$ \ $TIME(n)$ (the existence of such a language is guaranteer by the hierarchy theorem)
- Let *B* = {1}
- Note that $A \leqslant_{p} B, B \in TIME(n)$ but $A \not\in TIME(n^{3})$

The way I understand is that *A* is in $TIME(n^{3})$ but not in $TIME(n)$. I assume the main point in the proof is the polynomial reduction to *B*, but can we say that it is more or less than $n^{3}$?

I guess I would understand that in case the reduction can be completed in $O(n)$ then *A* can actually be solved in $TIME(n)$ which indeed is a contradiction..

Comment: A cannot be solved in time $O(n)$ by hypothesis. The proof is not a proof contradiction, it is exhibiting two languages $A, B$ such that $B \in TIME(n)$ but $A \not \in TIME(n)$, yet $A \le_p B$, which means that $TIME(n)$ is not closed under poly-time reductions. The time spent to compute the reduction does not matter (as long as it is polynomial, which can be guaranteed to be the case since $A$ can be solved in polynomial time by hypothesis). Also, you have a typo in the last item, it should be $A \not\in TIME(n)$.

Comment: Ahh I see. But why does it not matter what is the time of the reduction?
Oh yes the typo now makes sense, thank you!